# Change drawer gap between header group and first item menu

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I need change the space between header group and first item menu, here's an example:

[image]

I have seen a lot of examples and posts but only be can change the space for all items, **and I just need to change only for header group**.

Any idea?

Comment: Please share the code that is relevant to your current configuration of nav drawer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to **azizbekian**, his answer gived to me a great idea (maybe not the best but in my case more simple and fast to implement).
Basically, I add a layout with the same name (this will override it).
After that I change all that I need, so the result is this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[There are](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L399) 4 types of items in the `RecyclerView` that `NavigationView` creates:

```
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL:
                return new NormalViewHolder(mLayoutInflater, parent, mOnClickListener);
            case VIEW_TYPE_SUBHEADER:
                return new SubheaderViewHolder(mLayoutInflater, parent);
            case VIEW_TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                return new SeparatorViewHolder(mLayoutInflater, parent);
            case VIEW_TYPE_HEADER:
                return new HeaderViewHolder(mHeaderLayout);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The one you are interested in is [`SubheaderViewHolder`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L308). [`R.layout.design_navigation_item_subheader`](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design/blob/master/res/layout/design_navigation_item_subheader.xml#L19) is the layout, that would be inflated for that `ViewHolder`.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:paddingLeft="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
          android:paddingRight="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
          android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
          android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary"/>
```

As you can see, the height is taken from the theme's `listPreferredItemHeightSmall` attribute. But you cannot achieve your requirement just by changing the value of `listPreferredItemHeightSmall`, because [`NormalViewHolder`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L298)'s item [is also dependent](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design/blob/master/res/layout/design_navigation_item.xml#L20) on that value, thus changing it would affect all other items too.

The sneaky and non-reliable way of achieving that would be to acquire this `RecyclerView` on runtime with [`getIdentifier()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) API. The id of the custom `RecyclerView` is [`design_navigation_view`](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design/blob/master/res/layout/design_navigation_menu.xml#L19). Once acquired, you can manually get the actual `View` from `RecyclerView` (knowing which child of `RecyclerView` is the one you need). Then you can manually change the height of that `View`. But that is not reliable, because:

- It won't be easy to handle that for many such items, because you cannot know how many of them are actually displayed (well, you can, but is it worth it?)
- You have to listen for scroll events and detect when any new `SubheaderViewHolder` is getting displayed - then apply your custom height.

I cannot find enough seams to affect the height of that item. Your best option would be to provide your custom layout as the content of `NavigationView`.

Comment: You are a genius!, because with the info that you give me about design_navigation_item_subheader, I found a solution for my problem. Basically I create a layout with the same name and I change de padding that I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the best way to handle nav drawer is to have it display a full `Fragment`. This allows you to have a total control of its layout and behavior.

Comment: I understand, but I have not time and resources for do a refactor on this component. I try to find a workaround (a hack), I know that I can get the recyclerView from the NavigationView with this code `(RecyclerView) ((NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation)).getChildAt(0);`, so my plan is get the view from each viewholder from recycler, but for the moment I could not do it. Have you ever done this?

Answer (score -1):

Changing the values in `dimen.xml` by overriding the values which are already set in the android support library.

```
 <dimen name="design_navigation_padding_top_default"
tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding"tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_padding_bottom"tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
```

Comment: This override the padding between all rows. This does not work for me, I need only change the space in the section that was marked on the screenshot.

Comment: @GastonFlores yes, same way we can find the margin value from the library between header and it's first item and change it's  value.

Comment: @GastonFlores I think [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/res/values/dimens.xml) will help you achieve what you want. Overriding the values directly from the library.